# `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` Never Gets Caught

Tags: android, authentication, firebase

I wonder why `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` never gets caught. Whenever it is `WEAK_PASSWORD`, the `FirebaseException` is thrown instead of `FirebaseAuthException` or `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException`. Thus, I cannot check even with `getErrorCode()` method.

```
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // registered
                    } else {
                        try {
                            throw task.getException();
                        } catch(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                            passwordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_weak_password));
                            passwordEditText.requestFocus();
                        } catch(FirebaseException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can I know if it is the `WEAK_PASSWORD` exception?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're trying to create a user with a password LESS than 6 characters and the `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` is not caught?

Comment: I think it's a Firebase bug.  `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException` is returned and can be caught for a malformed email address and `FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException` if user already exists, but not `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` for weak password.

Comment: `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` is caught on my end and your code is similar to mine.You always have the option to perform a validation check on client side too (check if `password` is less than 6 characters).

Comment: `getException()` won't fall into `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` with password less than 6 characters. I guess, I need to validate manually like you said.

Comment: @RamithDR @qbix Also, do you where is the returned string of `getErrorCode()` defined? I have looked through the documentation but no luck.

Comment: @RamithDR: What version of Firebase produces `FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException` for you?  I tested with 10.2.0 and  get only `FirebaseException`.

Comment: @qbix The version could be the case, I'm using 10.0.1

Comment: If you've found a bug, you can [send a report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)

Comment: @all I think it's a bug in 10.2.0

Comment: @JoãoOliveira: Agree.  I confirmed that it works with 10.0.1 but not 10.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same problem. I am currently using firebase 10.2.4. For some reason it throws a Firebase Exception and not a FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException. My solution was to validate the length of password on the client side and if the length is less than 6 characters I display a Toast to the user.

```
private void signUp(){
    email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(email.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter your email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    if(password.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enter your password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }else if(password.length() < 6){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Your password is too week please enter a password more than 6 characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

   signUpFirebeaseListener.createNewUser(email,password);

}
```